# Hausman Test and RE results in Stata

Tags: mixed-model, fixed-effects-model, hausman

I was interested in doing a panel regression so I read around on the topic and found that there are two ways to go about it. You can either do a fixed effect regression or a random effects regression and to determine which one is best for your data, you perform a Hausman Test. Now my question is other than the Hausman test are there any other tests that need to be done on panel data? Or once the Hausman test is done do I accept the model and proceed to interpret the results accordingly?

Comment: I would rewrite the question to remove references to Stata (spelled thus; not STATA). I am in no sense hostile to Stata, but asking about code is generally off-topic here.

Comment: Oh, my apologies and noted with thanks. My question is really less on the coding and more on the whether there may be other tests I need to do before I can accept my model and interpret results.

Comment: Fine, and as suggested please rewrite accordingly.